# I set VISIBILITY of textview to VISIBLE in getView() of ListView - it remains visible for the next rows as well. How to solve this?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, adapter

Inside each row of my `ListView`, I want a `TextView` (which was originally given `android:visibility="gone"` in XML) to become visible only if a condition is satisfied.

So I do something like the following pseudocode.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    ...
   if (ape.getAlpha() != null && ape.getAlpha().equals("RON") ) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Item_textView5);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            }
        });
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } 
    ...
}
```

Now, *since each row is recycled and `getView()` is called again, once the `(ape.getAlpha() != null && ape.getAlpha().equals("RON"))` condition is satisfied in a row, and thus the `textview`'s `visibility` is set to `View.VISIBLE`, **it remains visible for the next rows as well.***

**The question is that how can I reset the visibility of the `textview` after setting it to `View.VISIBLE` for the next rows for which this row's layout will be recycled**, so that the reset visibility to `gone` is NOT reflected in the current row, but is NOT visible for the next rows which will use this same row's layout?

Comment: Simpley add a `else` clause where you set the visibility to `GONE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an else part as suggested in comments and move your `textView` initialization to out of the if block as-

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Item_textView5);
if (ape.getAlpha() != null && ape.getAlpha().equals("RON") ) {
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
    });
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put `textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` at the top of your function. That would force all the textView to always be gone until they meet the condition.